# Migrate mySQL data from php5.2 to php7

Tags: mysql, laravel, encoding, php-7.3, php-5.2

We have a really old codebase with `php5.2` some of them even in `php3` using `mysql 5.1` that we are trying to migrate to `laravel 7/8`. The data stored in the database is Japanese characters stored using `latin1` encoding as,

- `¥í¥°¥¤¥óÀ®¸ù`
- `¥í¥°¥¢¥¦¥È`
- `¥á¡¼¥ë¥¢¥É¥ì¥¹ÊÑ¹¹`

Those data are displayed correctly when using `php5.2` and are working fine in the current codebase but when I try to access that data using any version beyond `php5.2` I cannot get the correct value.

**Things I tried but didn't work.**

- Changed the file encoding with `header` in php file.
- Changed string encoding with `mb_convert_encoding`.
- Set `default_charset` in `php.ini` to empty string.

But none of the solutions seems to work. Is there any other way I can correctly display those data?

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=dbname;host=127.0.0.1;port=3306';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM tablename');
if ($query->execute()) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
        echo '<li>' . $row['column_name'] . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

The same block of code displays correct data in the browser using `php5.2` but it doesn't work in `php7.3`, how is that possible?

Comment: Could [this info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) possibly help? There's quite a bit involved.

Comment: The problem is, I already have existing data that I need to convert in order for them to work with newer versions of `PHP` instead of setting up a completely new environment.

Comment: @LalitThapa How do you think about creating a new database with `utf8mb4` ạnd importing the existing data?

Comment: Yeah, I already tried that but same problem with newer versions of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the charset in the dsn, something like

```
$db = new PDO('dblib:host=host;dbname=db;charset=utf8mb4', $user, $pwd);
```

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#php

More on Mojibake:  [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)